# big space between imagesview ( RecyclerView )

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, imageview

i'm trying to create an wallpaper application but i have this problem with `recyclerView` There is a big space between photos qnd spaced apart like this 
photo

[image]

and i don't why Appears in this format **Width** larger than  **Height**

[image]

java :

```
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container, Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    List<String> movieList =  new ArrayList<>();
    movieList.add("https://lh3.ggpht.com/-yKfQjOKJq9HcsOqzdCfpP-POQgEtJb43RZAQjEn10XiOEgM_CBgndV7stWe67wXiCq5=h900");
    movieList.add("http://www.botherland.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Samsung-Galaxy-S4-Black-Edition-Wallpaper-16.jpg");
    movieList.add("http://www.botherland.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Samsung-Galaxy-S4-Black-Edition-Wallpaper-5.jpg");
    movieList.add("http://www.androidhive.info/wp-content/uploads/2016/01/android-recycler-view-example.png");
    movieList.add("https://encrypted-tbn1.gstatic.com/images?q=tbn:ANd9GcTygBxBtnlvqcQR5GmFCvD1rvPUJJeHLm6lH2zckeYQ6XScoutwN0NgaG0");
    movieList.add("http://www.botherland.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/04/Samsung-Galaxy-S4-Black-Edition-Wallpaper-14.jpg");
    View v =  inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_art, container, false);
    recyclerView = (RecyclerView) v.findViewById(R.id.recycler_view);
    mAdapter = new MoviesAdapter(movieList,getContext());
    final StaggeredGridLayoutManager stg= new StaggeredGridLayoutManager(2, StaggeredGridLayoutManager.VERTICAL);
    recyclerView.setLayoutManager(stg);
    recyclerView.setItemAnimator(new DefaultItemAnimator());
    recyclerView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
    return v;
}

public class MoviesAdapter extends RecyclerView.Adapter<MoviesAdapter.MyViewHolder> {
    private List<String> moviesList;
    class MyViewHolder extends RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        public ImageView pic ;

        public MyViewHolder(View view) {
            super(view);
           pic = (ImageView)view.findViewById(R.id.imageView);
        }
    }
    public Context context;
    int screenWidth,screenHeight;
    MoviesAdapter(List<String> moviesList, Context context) {
        this.moviesList = moviesList;
        this.context=context;
        WindowManager wm = (WindowManager) getActivity().getSystemService(getActivity().WINDOW_SERVICE);
        Display display = wm.getDefaultDisplay();
        Point size = new Point();
        display.getSize(size);
        screenWidth = size.x;
        screenHeight = size.y;
    }
    @Override
    public MyViewHolder onCreateViewHolder(ViewGroup parent, int viewType) {
        View itemView = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext())
                .inflate(R.layout.picture_item, parent, false);
        return new MyViewHolder(itemView);
    }

    @Override
    public void onBindViewHolder(MyViewHolder holder, int position) {
       String pic  = moviesList.get(position);
        Glide.with(context).load(pic).placeholder(R.drawable.j).override(screenWidth/2,screenHeight/4).centerCrop().into(holder.pic);
}
    @Override
    public int getItemCount() {
        return moviesList.size();
    }
}
```

xml :

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:background="#fff"
tools:context="maa.a4kandhdwallpapers.Art">
<!-- TODO: Update blank fragment layout -->
   <android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="match_parent"
       android:id="@+id/recycler_view"/>
 </LinearLayout>
```

picture_item.xml :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:orientation="vertical" android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/imageView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Can u please  provide your list item layout file?

Comment: @pRaNaY please check my update

Comment: @AliILa provide `R.layout.picture_item.xml`

Comment: want to see picture_item layout file. I think issue is in item layout file?

Comment: @pRaNaY please check my new update

Comment: @AliILa make wrap_content in linearlayout layout_height in R.layout.picture_item.xml

Comment: @sanidhyapal thanks so much i have another question how i can fix **Width** and **Height**

Comment: @AliILa By fix u mean?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Change your **picture_item.xml** as:

```
<LinearLayout 
     xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
     xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
     android:orientation="vertical" 
     android:layout_width="match_parent"
     android:layout_height="wrap_content">

   <ImageView
       android:layout_width="match_parent"
       android:layout_height="wrap_content"
       android:id="@+id/imageView" />
</LinearLayout>
```

But if your image height is large, you will have same problem. I suggest you to fix the height if that does not create problem.

Comment: yeap i have this problem Some photos are regular and others are scattered please see this pic to understand me :
[link](http://i91.fastpic.ru/big/2017/0502/9d/02c16f75119077e0c5ef2f01e0ce109d.png)

Comment: You can fix the height and width of the imageView and then autofit the image as ** android:scaleType="scaleXY" ** .

Comment: Shrestha Sorry For Disturb but when i put this line  `android:scaleType="scaleXY"`  in imageView he gave me cannot resolve symbol scaleXY

Comment: Oops missed that. Please use "FIT_XY" instead of "scaleXY".

Comment: thank you so much but still i have problem **default image**  Very large please see this pic : 

https://i.imgur.com/A5arkpI.jpg

Comment: add this line **android:adjustViewBounds="true"**